# Jquery sliding DIV not working in browser compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a sliding div over pdf (Information : Pdf is Shown using iFrame). Its working on Mozilla Firefox, Chrome but its not working on Internet Explorer, Safari :(. Here is the jsFiddler Link. [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rickjackson/7VCeD/2/)

Will any 1 let me know what should i do to work in all browsers.

Comment: *but its not working on Internet Explorer* why not ? what error ? what happens ?

Comment: The Sliding effect is not working on the IE & Safari but others its working so just want help where i am getting wrong ? Also I have posted the fiddler link check that in the Post.

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

I think decent css is the key here

Comment: Hello Ruben.. Thanks for your reply.. I know this might will work but i want know how can i solve my implementation ?